# How to retrieve data from database and display in jsp using springs mvc?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to load the data from database and insert into dropdown:
am not able to retrieve the data

My javascript looks like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function getEmployee(row)
     {

     // $('#brand'+row)[0].options.length = 0;

        var xmlhttp;   
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {//code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5 
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
           {
               var status=xmlhttp.responseText;

               var x = document.getElementById("employee"+row);
               var option = document.createElement("option");
               option.text = "";
               x.add(option);
               var temp = status.split("#");
               for(var i=1;i<temp.length;i++)
               {
                    var temp_val=temp[i].split("//");
                    $('#employee'+row).append( new Option(temp_val[1],temp_val[0]));
                   }
           }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","LoadEmployee",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
     }

     function loadEmployee()
        {
            for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
                {
                    getEmployee(i)
                }
        }
```

I am trying to load data to below dropdown in the same jsp:

```
      <%
        int i=1;
     {%>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
    Employees <span class="symbol required"></span>
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="employee<%=i %>" path="employee<%=i     %>"  >

    </select>
    </div>
    <%} %>
```

My Controller as follows:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/LoadEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET) public void LoadEmployee(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, IllegalStateException, IOException 
{       

        System.out.println("In Load Brands");

        String employee=homeDao.getEmployee();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(employee);
}
```

My Implementation as follows:

public class Homeimpl implements HomeDao{

```
@Override
public String getEmployee() {
    String models="";
    String query = "SELECT member_name FROM mobike.mst_memberdetail;";
    System.out.println(query);
    try
    {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;
    Connection con = com.mobike.datasource.DbConnection.getDataSource();


            st = con.createStatement();
            rs  = st.executeQuery(query); 


            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

    return models;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to think about the architecture of the application, and what should be responsible for each part.

The V in MVC stands for View. Your controller method returns void, so is not returning a view at all. Instead, you are writing directly to the response output stream.

A JSP is a view file. Your controller method should add things to the model (in your case, the `Employee`), and then return the logical view name. The view (the JSP) would have placeholders to resolve model attributes (eg: ${employee})

Having said this, the above is true for a traditional MVC application, where it is based around a full page request/response.
You are using javascript (some very old-school JS btw, have you considered using a library such as angular or even jquery to simplify this for you?). Anyway, your JS appears to be making an ajax request to get the employee data.
With this in mind, your first page of html can be loaded into the browser without a Spring MVC controller method. It can be a simple static html file with the js (but ideally the js would itself be a separate static file)
When the js makes it's ajax request, you only need it to return the employee `representation` - you don't need the full jsp view. Your js callback can then interpolate the returned data into the DOM
My use of the phrase `representation` above is deliberate, as what I've started to describe here is more in line with a RESTful architecture (though there is more to REST than simply returning representations of objects)

I'm guessing you are fairly new to this and are probably following a tutorial or two? I think your best option would be to read around the subject a little more to understand what the different components do, and to find a more up to date tutorial.